# How to apply a model from the Model Zoo which has bigger input size than the OpenCV OAK-D's resolution(FHD 1920x1080)

Tags: opencv, intel, openvino, movidius, luxonis

Just wondering if I choose [a model](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/models/public/fastseg-small) from the Model Zoo which has bigger input size than the [OPEN-CV OAK-D](https://store.opencv.ai/products/oak-d)'s resolution(FHD 1920x1080) it errors out.

To be more specific, I am trying to deploy a model which can be the fastseg-small or [icent-camvid-ava-sparse-60-0001](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/models/intel/icnet-camvid-ava-sparse-60-0001) or [semantic-segmentation-adas-0001](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/models/intel/semantic-segmentation-adas-0001) onto the OpenCV OAK-D device.

when using `python depthai_demo.py -cnn semantic-segmentation-adas-0001` to deploy the model to OAK-D, I received this error:

```
Using depthai module from:  /media/winstonfan/Workspace/Learning/Github/depthai/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/depthai.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
Depthai version installed:  2.8.0.0
Available devices:
[0] 14442C10013762D700 [X_LINK_UNBOOTED]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "depthai_demo.py", line 180, in <module>
    device.startPipeline(pm.p)
RuntimeError: , LRT: 'ColorCamera(4) - 'preview' width or height (2048, 1024) bigger than sensor resolution (1920, 1080)'
```

So it seems that this model requires bigger input size.

How to use a model which requires input size larger than OAK-D's resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The fastseg-small, icent-camvid-ava-sparse-60-0001 and semantic-segmentation-adas-0001 models are not listed in [DepthAI Github repository](https://github.com/luxonis/depthai/tree/main/resources/nn), as such it might not be supported. You can post this question at the DepthAI [Community forum](https://discord.com/invite/EPsZHkg9Nx), or [Discussion forum](https://discuss.luxonis.com/). For your information, DepthAI and OpenCV OAK-D is not a part of OpenVINO Toolkit.

Comment: Hi IS, do you know what values of MyriadX compile params could be on this page? http://luxonis.com:8080/   I cannot find it anywhere.